# Arrangements put you in money

Tags: cryptic-crosswords, printers-devilry

[image]
[Grid in plaintext](https://pastebin.com/7CefUmYT)

**Note**: Eleven clues are **printer's devilry** with thematic answers.

**Across**
1. By the 1980s, his style of music hanged (4)
3. They had the hammer my bricks as the mason was absent (6)
9. According to Europeans (no male among them), it is a syndrome (9)
10. Montreal player exiting tumultous Abu Dhabi emirate (5)
11/12. For example, the UK monarch's museum in London (9,5)
13. Icons, IDs on able gentlemen (7)
16. Was this Norseman asked? (6)
19. Insult British lady before ultimately fleeing (3)
21. Steven Strange's social functions (6)
22. Arrangements put you in money (7)
24. Darkly dreaming Dexter's head removed – and the heart, perhaps? (5)
26. Turning upward pen-like presents after Christmas (9)
29. Body parts of different shade (5)
31. Jack and Lauren finally dancing in school (9)
32. Maybe Andy Warhol produced art describing repeating slogan (6)
33. We recently moved from Delhi as coast (4)

**Down**
1. This is the most beautiful baseball signed (4,5)
2. Clothes rack of more attractive female's missing (5)
3. Wild beast eating last of men gone missing (6)
4. Raising a pet for a 14 down, maybe (3)
5. His parents, Mr. and Ms. Clay, knew another name (5)
6. Father's stadium entrance ticket (4)
7. Secluded, extremely reclusive and weary (7)
8. Small guns are fine, but if it's a large cask, you to leave it home (7)
12. Army head covering ambush a Korean's hiding (5)
14. Bird seen over a new moon (5)
15. Trouble in Peoria, Illinois (3)
17. First course against former opposition leader (9)
18. You need to clean the hand roughly, that it shines (7)
20. Secretly landing at wicked airport (7)
23. The pent's mostly fish (6)
25. Can you, we, inch? Or using these scales? (5)
27. Instrument used in samba in abundance (1,4)
28. Sci-fi work reproduced nude (4)
30. 4 down is prepared (3)

Comment: Honestly jafe, you get all the way to Z, mission complete... *and then you start all over again!!* You can't help yourself, can you?! ;-) Make sure you allow yourself a break at some point!

Comment: @Stiv Hehe, I'd love to get twice through the alphabet -- that would make it almost exactly 1 year, and who doesn't love round numbers? :P It probably won't happen, though, at least on a weekly basis... I've had a buffer of 3-4 puzzles for most of this run, but with this one it's now officially gone down to zero.

Comment: @Stiv Missing the opportunity to continue with the Greek alphabet this time :-(

Comment: @Randal'Thor Or Chinese characters, for the real challenge!

Comment: @jafe ... 辛苦你了！

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grid:

> [image]

The clues:

> ACROSS
> 1 pd musiC HAD changed
> 3 pd they had the hammer mAN GO LAy bricks
> 9 as per Germans  - man
> 10 ABUDHABI* - Hab (Montreal Canadien player)
> 11/12 sovereigns + tate
> 13 pd I considER IT REAsonable, gentlemen
> 16 pd was this norMAL, A WIse man asked
> 19 Di + _g
> 21 steven*
> 22 'lats' (Latvian curr.) containing 'you'
> 24 Morgan - M
> 26 upwardpen*
> 29 shade*
> 31 __n + inschool*
> 32  man + art*
> 33 pd delhi TO GOa's coast
> DOWN
> 1 pd baseball CAP EVER DEsigned
> 2 fairer - f
> 3 beast* containing __n 
> 4 dog (reversed)
> 5 pd  knew aLI BY Another
> 6 pa's + s_
> 7 r_e + tired
> 8 pd  large caLIBER I Ask
> 12 hidden ambuSHAKOrean
> 14 tit + an
> 15 hidden peoriAILlinois
> 17 anti + past + o_
> 18 clean the handLE SO THOroughly
> 20 hidden landinGATWICKed
> 23 pd the penGUIN EAts mostly fish
> 25 pd weiGH AN Anchor
> 27 double def'n
> 28 nude*
> 30 double def'n (Set is an Egyptian god)

Comment: For 32A I think it's just a case that rot13(Znlor Naql Jneuby = ZNA, cebqhprq neg* = GEN). Well done :)

Comment: @Stiv - I'll go with that, but add a question mark to it, as I am not certain. Thanks.

Comment: rot13(Cebqhprq vf whfg na nantenz vaqvpngbe.) Nice work!